# Validating a datetime fully using jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

Im using the built in jQuery validation

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Works fine on all fields so far, except datetime. Its ok, but not fool proof. I can only type numbers and slashes.

But that means I can type in `3/4//4///4//` which of course throws back a null parameter on submit as it doesn't fit to datetime anymore. (I do use a datepicker to select this, but you can still type in the box.)

So I need:

- either a way to ensure it's of `##/##/####` format
- or to prevent being able to manually type in the box, only use the datetime picker

Comment: Your suggested edit to the answer isn't appropriate; if it's significantly different, you should post it as an answer and then accept it. Otherwise, just leave it and accept that, possibly mentioning how it was appropriate to you in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used the Regex attribute on my model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$", ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid date of format dd/mm/yyyy.")]
```

This validates on the form dd/mm/yyyy and ensures valid dates, including leap years.

**EDIT:**

A better way to do such validations would be Custom Validation Attributes. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.aspx

Google it for tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the readonly attribute of the box however that still allows the user to highlight text for copying etc. I usually prefer to use the disabled attribute as this prevents the user from manipulating or using the box. The only downside to using disabled is that the box will not be submitted upon submitting the form but if this is not a problem then I prefer to use that attribute.

Another option is to write your own javascript function to perform the validation. I have one that I wrote a long time ago somewhere that I could help you out with if you would like to use that method.

Comment: +1 for good suggestions. I have found a regex attribute I can assign to ensure it is of the exact format I desire. Even accepts leap years and only valid dates. .. Its very long :O

Comment: Excellent. I hadn't actually considered a regex for some reason.